# Bash loop with two values

Tags: r, bash, loops, for-loop, syntax

I'm trying to run a for loop where I want both the initial value ($f in the example) and the value plus a constant ($f + 2000) to play a role in the loop. However (for obvious reasons) it won't run with ($f+2000) in the command.

```
for f in `seq 1 1000`; 
     do tabix my.vcf.gz 1:$f-($f+2000) > chr1.$f.vcf
done
```

Any suggestions about how to make this work or another strategy?

I have also tried using the system command in R to run the loop, but my syntax there is even uglier and doesn't work either (copied below).

Thanks in advance!

R

```
for (i in 1:1000) {system('tabix my.vcf.gz 1:'i'-'(i+2000)' > chr1.'i'.vcf')}
```

Comment: To begin ``for $f in `seq 1 1000`; `` should be ``for f in `seq 1 1000`; ``

Comment: True! My dumb mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following:

```
for f in {1..10}
do
    echo tabix my.vcf.gz 1:$f-$(($f+2000)) = chr1.$f.vcf
done
```

produces

```
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:1-2001 = chr1.1.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:2-2002 = chr1.2.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:3-2003 = chr1.3.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:4-2004 = chr1.4.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:5-2005 = chr1.5.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:6-2006 = chr1.6.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:7-2007 = chr1.7.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:8-2008 = chr1.8.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:9-2009 = chr1.9.vcf
tabix my.vcf.gz 1:10-2010 = chr1.10.vcf
```

if satisfied, remove the echo and change the `=` to `>`.